# AWS: CognitoUser.refreshSession vs AWS.config.credentials.refresh

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm coding a webapp and wondering about the differences between, and when to use, CognitoUser.refreshSession() and/or AWS.config.credentials.refresh() to refresh the session when, for instance, the user refreshes the page. Currently both work fine (using developer authenticated credentials)

The app uses IAM in the background and and makes direct API calls to lambda  (ie not via apigClient). This is working fine but calls are not being signed (ie, Authorization: session.getIdToken().getJwtToken() )

I would like to sign these calls using Signature 4 methods, but struggling to get anything other than a 401 Unauthorised response, and wondering if AWS.config.credentials are required for this, And if not, where and how to get the access and secret keys for signing.

I am also wondering if I need to do something special in lambda functions to receive these calls, or not.

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect this is also you: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=251234&tstart=0 , and a Cognito team member is looking at your question there.

Comment: That's correct yes :)